# How do I detect if a view appeared from the app being restored?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. I know I can use -`(void)viewWillAppear` for when an app is open to detect if the view is open or not. I want to Call code in my view when the app is restored and if the view is open, can anyone give me any pointers on how to do this please?

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the methods

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

in the AppDelegate to check if the app was restarted or is going to be closed.

Comment: And then you can post an NSNotification to alert your view that it's been "re-opened".

Comment: Yeah as Jeffrey Berthiaume already mentioned (before he deleted his comment) :)

Comment: Ah got it, that was me who deleted the comment asking if I should use NSNotifications! thanks

Comment: If I'm not misstaken those notifications are already sent by the framework. You just need to listen for them.

Comment: @Peter Segerblom - really? you can listen to them in other ViewControllers without registering to the notifications? I didn't knew that

Comment: Well you still need to register to listen to them but you don't need to override those methods in app delegate and post your own notifications. I think didBecomeActive is called: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Comment: ah ok nice, i got it.